# How bit torrent works in private network?

Tags: networking, private, bit, torrent

Can somebody please explain working of a bit torrent from the perspective of a host in private network as its IP address is not visible outside the private network. Is port forwarding necessary for bit torrent to work?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. The basic protocol still works if it can not accept incoming connections, it can rely on just outgoing connections. Of course if several peers are not accepting incoming connections, none of them can directly connect, and that's a bad thing - for those peers and for the whole swarm. The number of unreachable (but active) peers is significant in practice, though very hard to measure precisely.

Also, consider that your client will be advertising itself as available, so other peers will be wasting connection attempts to your client, which will be rejected by the NAT device (or they won't even really go anywhere, if the client is silly enough to advertise its private IP address).

So in short, it will work, but it's not a good thing.

For the UDP based protocols (UDP tracker, DHT, µtp), hole-punching can be used (except from behind symmetric NAT), so typically no forwarding is required for those (as long as the client supports hole-punching).

Comment: What will happen if torrent protocol does not allow leechers?

Comment: @user3038038 which definition of "leechers"? It doesn't really make sense to ban leechers of the definition commonly used with regards to BitTorrent, where it's just the opposite of a seeder (so downloaders in general).

Comment: @user3038038 anyway, a client that doesn't accept incoming connections can still upload over the connections that it initiates itself, as long as it does that the other clients will have no reason to penalize it.